# キャッシュを保存しないように .htaccess を設定する方法

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

今現在、ワードプレスで、VirtualBoxを使いサイトをローカルで作っています。

コード変更時にキャッシュが毎回残ってしまい、サイト制作の際に毎回キャッシュを消さないといけなくなってしまいます。

大変手間がかかりますので、.htaccess を編集して、キャッシュを保存しないように設定しようとしていますが、触れたことのないコードが使われていて、よく分かりません、
とりあえず下記のように入力しましたが、上手くいきません。

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
# Modified Time: 07-01-22 16:24:21
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pacificmall.local
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=kei
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pacificmall.local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WP_FASTEST_CACHE_CSS_VALIDATOR|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/kusanagi/pacificmall/DocumentRoot/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache


<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files wp-login.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    #Allow from 127.0.0.1
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "ENTER YOUR NAME & PASSWORD TO LOGIN"
    AuthUserFile /home/kusanagi/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy any
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|css|js|swf|jpeg|jpg|jpe|png|ico|swd|pdf|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 # データはキャッシュさせない
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml    
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess にどのように入力すれば、キャッシュの保存をふせげますでしょうか？
こちらが参考にしたサイトです。

[.htaccess の書き方（スピードアップ編）](https://qiita.com/shotets/items/a5465fb41623cc3dae94)

もし、.htaccess を編集しなくとも、キャッシュを一回一回削除しなくていい方法があるのでしたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: .htaccess で設定するのと (ブラウザの) 検証ツールでキャッシュを無効化するのとでは意味合いが異なってきますが、元々求めていたのは検証時にブラウザでのキャッシュが無効にできればよい、という事だったのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、キャッシュを自動で無効化することが目的です。

Answer (score 1):

検証ツールの、Networkタブにある「Disable cache」にチェックを付けることでキャッシュを無効にすることができました。